# Simple IF Else, but crashes the Command Box when I try to generate an error

Tags: c, dev-c++

So yeah, the title says it all. It's weird because, on another part of the code, I can execute it properly, it just screws up and I'm just dead confused.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
char EMPname[50], EMPgender[5], EMPposition[5];
int EMPage;
printf ("Midterm Examination, BSCS (ERCA)\n");
printf ("Welcome, employee!\n");
printf ("Please Input your name: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]s", &EMPname);
printf ("Age: ");
scanf ("%d", &EMPage);
printf ("Gender(M|F): ");
scanf ("%s", &EMPgender);
printf ("Position(P|PA|SP): ");
scanf ("%s", &EMPposition);
printf ("\n\n--------------------\n\n");
if(strcmp(EMPgender, "M")== 0|| strcmp(EMPgender, "m")== 0){
    if (strcmp(EMPposition, "P")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "p")== 0){
        printf ("%s is a Programmer.\n", EMPname);
    }else if (strcmp(EMPposition, "PA")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "pa")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "pA")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Pa")== 0){
        printf ("%s is a Program Analyst.\n", EMPname);
    }else if (strcmp(EMPposition, "SP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sp")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Sp"== 0)){
        printf ("%s is a Senior Programmer.\n", EMPname);
    }else{
        printf ("%s has no position.\n", EMPname);
    }
    printf ("Age: %d, Gender: Male\n", EMPage);
}else if (strcmp(EMPgender, "F")== 0|| strcmp(EMPgender, "f")== 0){
        if (strcmp(EMPposition, "P")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "p")== 0){
        printf ("%s is a Programmer.\n", EMPname);
    }else if (strcmp(EMPposition, "PA")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "pa")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "pA")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Pa")== 0){
        printf ("%s is a Program Analyst.\n", EMPname);
    }else if (strcmp(EMPposition, "SP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sp")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Sp"== 0)){
        printf ("%s is a Senior Programmer.\n", EMPname);
    }else{
        printf ("%s has no position.\n", EMPname);
    }
    printf ("Age: %d, Gender: Female\n", EMPage);
}else{
    if (strcmp(EMPposition, "P")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "p")== 0){
        printf ("%s is a Programmer.\n", EMPname);
    }else if (strcmp(EMPposition, "PA")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "pa")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "pA")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Pa")== 0){
        printf ("%s is a Program Analyst.\n", EMPname);
    }else if (strcmp(EMPposition, "SP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sp")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Sp"== 0)){
        printf ("%s is a Senior Programmer.\n", EMPname);
    }else{
        printf ("%s has no position.\n", EMPname);
    }
    printf ("Age: %d, Gender: Unknown\n", EMPage);
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

What the program does is a simple input and output, but the IF ELSE part requires us to compare chars. The expected input at the EMPposition and EMPgender part is the one that's causing the most problems here.

Edit: I showed my entire code this time, soz.

Comment: How are `EMPposition` and `EMPname` defined? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is `EMPposition`? What is `EMPname`? How are they initialized? Can you please try to create an [mcve] to show us?

Comment: And always copy-paste (as text!) the actual error in full and complete into the body of the question. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sorry, and thank you sir. I'm quite new to this.

Comment: OT: If scanning into a `char` array using `s` do not pass the address of the array (like this `scanf ("%s", &EMPposition);`), but the address of its 1st character, like this `scanf ("%s", &EMPposition[0]);` which in fact is the same as just doing  `scanf ("%s", EMPposition);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a misplaced parantheses in the line:

```
if (strcmp(EMPposition, "SP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sp")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "sP")== 0 || strcmp(EMPposition, "Sp"== 0))
```

To correct it replace

```
strcmp(EMPposition, "Sp"== 0)
```

with

```
strcmp(EMPposition, "Sp") == 0
```

You pass the result of `"Sp" == 0`, which results in `0`, to the `strcmp` function which then tries to dereference it, invoking undefined behavior.

Your compiler should give you a warning, on gcc i get:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. That honestly f*cked me up for 30 minutes straight. I'm using Dev C++, which didn't give me a warning for that so I might consider changing it. 

Thanks! ^^